# Using Mac as Network Gateway

Tags: network, wifi, vpn, internet-sharing

Currently this is my setup

```
Internet <--  Mac Pro (Wifi). shared over Ethernet <-- PC (Ethernet)
```

The default network sharing is very limited. I am able to share my Mac Wifi over ethernet and connect to internet. However this bypasses all VPN routing/VPN setup in Mac and I believe MacOS treats Network sharing as independent connection.

1. Mac should act as Network Gateway or a way where I can route all my requests from PC as if they are originated from Mac (routing through VPN).
2. PC shouldn't query Mac for local IP addresses (192.168.x.x)

PC is running on Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: A) What VPN product? B) Why not connect Linux box directly to internet (here assuming that the Internet connection is a router)? Your Q1 (is it a question?): run VPN client on Linux. Your statement 2: Where else could Linux get its IP address?

Comment: VPN Product - ZScalar. Currently my company doesn't distribute/support Linux VPN Client, that ruled out all options to connect directly from Linux machine.

Essentially I want to use Mac as Network Proxy/Gateway for my Linux machine so that all the traffic is routed through Mac

Comment: @Gilby let me know if needed any more information. I assumed this should be easy by forcing `bridge` interface to fall back to specific `utun` interface

Comment: Internet sharing (on a Mac) is not really a bridge (in the network layer model).  IT is a gateway (i.e. acts as a router) providing its own subnet 192.168.2.x for clients and so needs to be a DHCP server for those clients. But....

Comment: Never heard of ZScaler before. But a quick 3 minute read tells me it is not the usual consumer or enterprise VPN - both of which VPN at the network layer. ZScaler seems to be focused on VPN at the application layer. But I am getting out of my depth with a product I don't know!  I suggest you talk to your company network support people about this and, if appropriate, to get you the Ubuntu zScaler client.

Comment: @Gilby. I agree how it operates differently. 


> route get 8.8.8.8
   route to: dns.google
destination: dns.google
    gateway: 10.64.0.1
  interface: utun3

utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1300
 inet 10.64.0.1 --> 10.64.0.1 netmask 0xffff0000

Can't I force `bridge` interface to link to `utun3` simply?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134547/discussion-between-racebase-and-gilby).